# What constitutes the size of sql server database

Tags: sql-server

Can you help me to understand what consumes the 149MB difference between the figures calculated on screenshot. The sizes are produced by SP sp_spaceused

[image: result of sp_spaceused call]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first result of [sp_spaceused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) gives you the total size of the data and log files. The second result is just the data used; Reserved is data+index+unused.

In your example, the total size of the data and transaction log files will be 300MB.

```
    SELECT name,
       type,
       ROUND((size * 8.0) / 1024, 2)
    FROM sys.database_files;
```

Comment: It matches with the figures I see in DB, thanks. Wondering why log file grows despite DB being in simple recovery mode.

Comment: @Tomek, even in simple recover, the log needs to be big enough to accommodate the largest transaction.

Comment: To expand on Dan's comment, this is to account for an active transaction that may rollback. Simple Recovery Model just means the Transaction Log is immediately marked for re-use (without the need for backing it up) by other transactions.